# Angular: how to loop through a FormArray which is nested in a FormGroup which is already nested in a different FormGroup?

Tags: angular, forms, formbuilder, formarray

I use this block of code to create my form:

```
@Input() fetchedTask: Task;
taskForm: FormGroup;
formThresholds: FormArray;
```

```
this.taskForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            taskId: null,
            groupId: this.groupId,
            name: ["", [Validators.required]],
            taskType: this.taskTypeId,
            etc.
            configuration: this._formBuilder.group({
                name: ["", Validators.required],
                path: ["", Validators.required],
                thresholds: this._formBuilder.array([])
            })
        });
```

I later set values of the form using `setValue()`:

```
this.taskForm.controls["taskId"].setValue(this.fetchedTask.taskId);
```

I set the value of my FormArray using:

```
this.fetchedTask.configuration.thresholds.forEach((x)=>{
              this.addItem(x.value, x.name);
            })

addItem(value: number, name: string): void {
      this.formThresholds = this.taskForm.get('configuration.thresholds') as FormArray;
      this.formThresholds.push(this.createItem(value, name));
    }

createItem(value: number, name: string): FormGroup{
      return this._formBuilder.group({
        value: value,
        name: name
      });
    }
```

I really don't know how to approach looping through my array values and showing them in my form, with populated values.

I tried this but with no success:

```
        <div *ngFor="let threshold of taskForm.get('configuration.thresholds') let i = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Threshold name">
                <input formControlName="value" placeholder="Threshold value">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: try this taskForm['controls'].configuration.thresholds['controls']

Comment: @GouravGarg I get this error when trying your suggestion:

_Property 'thresholds' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'._

Comment: Can you try this ? taskForm['controls'].configuration['controls'].thresholds['controls'] or you simply can create a get property like get formArray():FormArray{return this.taskForm.get('configuration.thresholds') as FormArray;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gourav Garg and my fiddling I came up with an answer.

The problem was that I missed a parent div tag referring to the formGroup in which the formArray belongs - the 'configuration' form group.

So for this form structure:

```
this.taskForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            taskId: null,
            groupId: this.groupId,
            name: ["", [Validators.required]],
            taskType: this.taskTypeId,
            etc.
            configuration: this._formBuilder.group({
                name: ["", Validators.required],
                path: ["", Validators.required],
                thresholds: this._formBuilder.array([])
            })
        });

get thresholds(): FormArray{
      return this.formThresholds = this.taskForm.get('configuration.thresholds') as FormArray;
    }
```

if I want to show values from the threshold on my page I need 4 tags.
Example:

```
<form [formGroup]="taskForm">
    <div formGroupName="configuration">
        <div formArrayName="thresholds"
            *ngFor="let threshold of this.taskRunProfileForm['controls'].configuration['controls'].thresholds['controls']; let i = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                {{name.value}}
                {{value.value}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Either you can directly put in HTML as below:

```
*ngFor="let threshold of taskForm['controls'].configuration['controls'].thresholds['controls']; let i = index;"
```

or you can create a get property in component and use in html or ts file as well.

```
get formThresholds():FormArray{
    return this.taskForm.get('configuration.thresholds') as FormArray;
}
```

Comment: `taskForm['controls'].configuration['controls'].thresholds['controls'];` did the trick!
But now I'm getting an interesting set of errors: `"Cannot find control with name: '0'"`, `"Cannot find control with path: '0 -> name'"`, `Cannot find control with path: '0 -> value'`.

I've checked, and there is one FromGroup in my thresholds FormArray.

Comment: Can you check if return value of taskForm['controls'].configuration['controls'].thresholds['controls'][0].get('name') in console?

Comment: I've tried adding `formArrayName="formThresholds"` in my div tag:
`<div formArrayName="formThresholds" *ngFor="let threshold of this.taskRunProfileForm['controls'].configuration['controls'].thresholds['controls']; let i = index;">` but now I get an extra step in my erro messages:
`"Cannot find control with name: 'formThresholds'"`, `"Cannot find control with path: 'formThresholds -> 0'"`,  `"Cannot find control with path: 'formThresholds -> 0 -> name'"`

Comment: add this in formArrayName="formThresholds"

Comment: I did, the comment before yours. The return value of `taskForm['controls'].configuration['controls'].thresholds['controls'][0].get('name')` is as expected: `value:"Duration"`.

Interestingly I get a blank input for name and value property but there are no values in those inputs.

I've tried changing places where I initialize my form and bind data from NgOnChanges to NgOnInit, same results.

Comment: You haven't specified type. May be that's an issue Or you can always see like {{name.value}}

Comment: I did it! Solution in answers. Thanks for your help!